# How to set window attributes like class and type in Kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I'm developing a linux app with kivy and I need to set attributes to the x11 window (name, type and class), so that the window can behave properly. This is currently possible in tkinter by doing `root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy's window manipulation is exposed via the `kivy.core.window.Window` object, see [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html). Some of what you want is definitely exposed via properties but I'm not sure if all of it is, in which case you'd need to modify the Kivy source or use an external tool (possibly X interaction tools can do it) to change your window.